# ¿Cómo actualizar una columna con solo una consulta en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada programas, lo que quiero hacer es agregar una nueva columna que puede contener valores nulos.
Las columnas que tengo son:
id_p
editor
En la tabla tengo 20 registros, entonces en la nueva columna debo agregar un numero diferen, se que lo puedo hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
 UPDATE program SET nuevacol=10 WHERE id_p = 1;
 UPDATE program SET nuevacol=11 WHERE id_p = 2;
```

Puedo hacer esto con una sola consulta? Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Quieres agregar una columna? o ya tienes la columna y quieres actualizar esa columna?

Comment: Únicamente por sugerirte alternativas, ¿para qué necesitas algo así?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tratas de realizar actualiza el valor del campo `nuevacol` en la tabla `program` cuando `id_p = 1`

```
 UPDATE program SET nuevacol=10 WHERE id_p = 1;
```

para agregar una nueva columna en tu tabla necesitarías realizar de esta forma:

```
 ALTER TABLE program ADD "nombre de columna" "tipo de columna";
```

Answer (score 1):

Sería así:

```
UPDATE program SET nuevacol= id_p + 10;
```

Eso te va a actualizar todos los registros con el id + 10, así vas a tener un valor diferente en cada registro.

Para agregar el nuevo campo:

```
ALTER TABLE programas add nuevacol int;
```